# Where do I find the saving throws matrix for monsters in AD&D

Tags: monsters, adnd-1e, saving-throw

In the Dungeon Master's Guide it gives you a matrix for character saving throws but I can not find the matrix for monster's saving throws, where can I find this?

Comment: Is there a matrix? I thought they were just assigned to each monster on an "I think this is right" basis.

Comment: I always just gave the monsters the saves of whichever class seemed right, and then set their level as their HD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the same page as the character saving throw matrix (*DMG*, p. 79) is the heading:

> **II. SAVING THROW MATRIX FOR MONSTERS**

The section doesn't actually include a matrix, so it's easy to miss when doing a visual scan; rather it has a four-point explanation of how to figure their saving throws, the first point being that they use the same matrix as for PCs.

Comment: I swear I am blind some times, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @Jonn The organisation of the 1st edition of AD&D is horrendous! I knew it was bad, but never realised quite *how* bad it was until I started looking for solid answers to questions like this. These questions will very probably help others aplenty.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie My favorite example is in the 1E PHB.  There's a footnote on page 25 under "Fighters’, Paladins’, & Rangers’ attacks per melee round table" that says vs 1HD creatures those classes get 1 attack per character level.  It directs you to the Combat chapter, but I've *never* been able to find the actual cross reference!